# forward_list - Missing ";" before "<"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, forward-list

For a project, our professor has provided us with one .cpp file and three .h files containing Class definitions. The goal of the project is to construct the implementation .cpp files for these Classes.

I'm aware that `using namespace std;` is bad practice and should be avoided at all costs, but the teacher insists on three important points in the completion of the project:

1. **You must not modify any of the provided files. "Not a single character". (60% reduction in marks)**
2. It fails to build in Visual Studio 2017. (60% reduction in marks)
3. It crashes during normal operation. (60% reduction in marks)

My problem is that I'm receiving some errors pertaining to his definition of a `forward_list<>` in one of the Classes. These errors mean nothing to me... I've been scratching my head for the last few hours, while attempting to remedy these errors:

```
1>Animation.cpp
1>AnimationManager.cpp
1>c:\users\ali-g\desktop\cst8219\assignment2\assignment2\animation.h(7): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
1>c:\users\ali-g\desktop\cst8219\assignment2\assignment2\animation.h(7): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\ali-g\desktop\cst8219\assignment2\assignment2\animation.h(7): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>Ass2.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>Done building project "Assignment2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here is the .h file he provided, containing the Animation class definition:

```
//Animation.h
#pragma once

class Animation
{
    string animationName;
    forward_list<Frame> frames;
public:
    Animation(string name) :animationName(name) {}
    ~Animation() {}
    void EditFrame();
    void DeleteFrame();
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Animation&);// Add a Frame as in cin >> A;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Animation&);// output the Frames as in cout << A;
};
```

Here is my implementation .cpp file from Animation Class:

```
//Animation.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <forward_list>
using namespace std;
#include "Frame.h"
#include "Animation.h"

void Animation::EditFrame() {

}

void Animation::DeleteFrame() {

}

istream& operator>> (istream& in, Animation& animation) {


    return in;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Animation& animation) {


    return out;
}
```

The .h file he provided containing the definition for AnimationManager Class:

```
// AnimationManager.h
#pragma once

class AnimationManager
{
    string managerName;
    vector<Animation> animations;
public:
    AnimationManager(string name) :managerName(name) {}
    ~AnimationManager() {}
    void EditAnimation();
    void DeleteAnimation();
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, AnimationManager&);// add an Animation
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, AnimationManager&);// output the Animations
};
```

And here is my implementation file for AnimationManager Class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#include "Frame.h"
#include "Animation.h"
#include "AnimationManager.h"

void AnimationManager::EditAnimation() {

}

void AnimationManager::DeleteAnimation() {

}

istream & operator>>(istream &in, AnimationManager &manager){

    string name;

    cout << "Please enter Animation Name: ";
    cin >> name;

    //resize vector array to accommodate a new Animation
    manager.animations.resize(manager.animations.size() + 1);
    manager.animations.push_back(Animation(name));

}

ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, AnimationManager &manager){

}
```

I'll also include the .h & .cpp file for the other included header file (Frame.h), as it may help you find my (most likely stupid) mistake.

"Frame.h":

```
// Frame.h
#pragma once
class Frame{ 
    char* frameName; 
    double duration; 
public:
    Frame(char*, double); 
    Frame(const Frame&); 
    ~Frame(); 
    Frame& operator=(const Frame&); 
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Frame&); 
};
```

"Frame.cpp":

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Frame.h"

Frame::Frame(char* name, double dur) {

    //Set frame name
    frameName = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    strcpy(this->frameName, name);

    //set duration
    duration = dur;

}

Frame::Frame(const Frame& frame) {

    //copy name from passed frame
    frameName = new char[strlen(frame.frameName) + 1];
    strcpy(frameName, frame.frameName);

    //copy duration
    duration = frame.duration;

}

Frame::~Frame() {

    //free the space allocated for frameName
    if (frameName != nullptr) {
        delete[] frameName;
    }

}

Frame& Frame::operator= (const Frame& frame) {

    //create new Frame using given frame information
    Frame copyFrame = Frame(frame.frameName, frame.duration);

    //return reference to new frame.
    return copyFrame;

}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Frame& frame) {

    //add frameName and duration to ostream.
    out << "\tframeName - " << frame.frameName << "; ";
    out << "duration - " << frame.duration << endl;

    //return ostream
    return out;

}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help in solving this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Move the standard header include statements inside your header file, and don't use `using namespace std;`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Addressed in the question.

Comment: `string` and `forward_list` belong to the `std` namespace. (Issues in Animation.h.) Prefix both with `std::`.

Comment: It seems like the error is originating from compiling `AnimationManager.cpp`, which isn't present.

Comment: In `AnimationManager.cpp` you probably don't have `#include "Frame.h"` above `#include "Animation.h"`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ We're unable to edit the .h files supplied by the professor (or face a 60% reduction). Which is also why I'm forced into using the `using namespace std;` statement in my implementation files.

Comment: you can write your own wrapper headers :) it seems like the teacher don't forbid more files being created.

Comment: @ImAManiak, It's worth noting that you're still able to use `using std::blah;` instead of `using namespace std;`, but I can't say how much your professor likes the former.

Comment: moreover, you can write all the code on your own, so you don't *modify* his (broken) codes :)

Comment: @chris I updated the question with the source code for this file (with it's .h file). Thanks for opening my eyes.

Comment: Maybe you need `#include <forward_list>` in `AnimationManager.cpp` your assignment rules are really causing some bad design.

Comment: @drescherjm Wow, this is the second stupid mistake I make while writing this project (just imagine the despair in my voice)... Thank you very much for your answer, it solved my problem and returned my sanity!